# Recursively copy a directory entirely as symlinks, preserving current symlinks

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

I would like to make an exact copy of a directory (which contains sub-directories, files, and symlinks) except that I want each file in the target directory to be a symlink back to the original file.

This I can already accomplish using:

```
cp -sR /home/me/SourceDir TargetDir
```

However, I would like any relative symlinks within SourceDir that point to somewhere else in SourceDir to remain the same relative links, hence now pointing to TargetDir.

For example, let's say SourceDir contains the following:

```
File0
Dir1/File1
Dir1/File2
Dir2/File3
Dir2/File2   <-- this is a symlink to ../Dir1/File2
```

Then I would like TargetDir to look like:

```
File0        <-- symlink to  ../SourceDir/File0
Dir1/File1   <-- symlink to  ../../SourceDir/Dir1/File1
Dir1/File2   <-- symlink to  ../../SourceDir/Dir1/File2
Dir2/File3   <-- symlink to  ../../SourceDir/Dir2/File3
Dir2/File2   <-- this is still a symlink to ../Dir1/File2, so: TargetDir/Dir1/File2
```

I wouldn't mind if this had to be accomplished in two or three steps (something I could write into a simple shell script).

One thought I had was first copying all symlinks only, then doing the cp -sR with a no-clobber.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes me so curious: why?

Comment: I'm curious, too, why you want to do this. It would seem that a symlink to the directory itself would suffice.

Comment: Arjan, how I have shown it in the example is how I would like it to be.  In other words, in TargetDir, the Dir2/File2 is a link pointing to the other File2 within TargetDir, specifically to TargetDir/Dir1/File2.

Comment: Arjan, Ron, The reason for this is more complicated than my example lets on. Eventually, some files in TargetDir will be altered and other files will be created/added/deleted, and thus a simple symlink to the original directory itself will not suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said you are in `/home/me`, but your `cp` command will create all your links as absolute, wherever you are, ie `TargetDir/File0 -> /home/me/SourceDir/File0` etc, not the relative links you illustrate.

You can achieve what you want using `find`:-

```
cp -sR /home/me/SourceDir TargetDir
cd /home/me/SourceDir
find -type l -exec cp -P "{}" "/Path/To/TargetDir/{}" \;
```

- The first command is your original.
- By positioning yourself in the source directory you eliminate it from the find path.
- The `find` with `cp -P` overwrites the links with verbatim copies of the source links.
- The double-quotes allow for files and directories with embedded blanks.

If you really want relative links (`TargetDir/File0 -> ../../SourceDir/File0` etc) for your normal files, you will need to use `find -type f` and execute `mkdir -p` to create the target directory structure, then `find -type f` and execute `ls -s` for each file.

Comment: Nice note on the `cp` command; I didn't even think about that.

Comment: Perfect solution!  I also use the `symlinks` command to clean up links and make them relative.  From the `TargetDir/` just execute:  `symlinks -csr ./`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `symlinks`: I've not met it before, and it looks rather useful.