# Copy files as symlinks and maintain the directory structure on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, symbolic-link

I have looked at this question: [Recursively copy a directory entirely as symlinks, preserving current symlinks](https://superuser.com/questions/991721/recursively-copy-a-directory-entirely-as-symlinks-preserving-current-symlinks) and if I'm reading it right I want to do the same thing but in Windows.

So, I have this:

```
Dir1\Dir_A\File.ext
Dir1\Dir_A\Dir_A_A\file2.ext
Dir1\Dir_B\File2.ext
...
```

I want that directory structure to be the exact same on the target directory minus the Dir1 but all the files to be symlinks pointing to the source files. So, I end up with this:

```
Target_Dir\Dir_A\File.ext <- file is symlink, folders are created
Target_Dir\Dir_A\Dir_A_A\file2.ext <- file is symlink, folders are created
Target_Dir\Dir_B\File3.ext <- file is symlink, folders are created
...
```

How can I achieve this? I'm also looking for a batch script or something that can be executed on a schedule to copy the new files every so often skipping the already created symlinks, kinda like a synchronization job minus the real copying of the files but instead (sym)linking them.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thank you! That is exactly what I was requesting. It works well except for just one thing, I have a folder which name has a "!" character in the end and the batch has copied the folder without the "!" character and also has created a file with the folders name. To be more precise the name is like "AAAA AAAA! (1234)" and the batch has created a folder named "AAAA AAAA (1234)" and a file named "AAAA AAAA.mkv" (without the numbers on the filename), how can I fix this? The file points to a file with the same name in the source dir but that file doesn't exist.

Comment: I have also noticed that all the files that had a "!" in their filename has been copied without that character.

Comment: [delayedvariableexpansion - How to avoid delayed expansion removing the exclamation marks in file names? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690889/how-to-avoid-delayed-expansion-removing-the-exclamation-marks-in-file-names)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks! And sorry, I don't get it. What should I change in the pure batch script?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yes, after some testing I also got the batch to copy some files but no others, and after a subsequent test it didn't work at all, I don't know why it worked that one time. Would be awesome if you could make a Powershell script to see if maybe this doesn't happen in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PowerShell: Recursive folder copy with symbolic link files

You can use [get-childitem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html) to create an [array](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html) variable and [loop](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html) over the iterated object properties with some conditional [if](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html) logic to help create a workable solution for your needs.

> **Essentially this...**
>
> - creates a source-matching destination folder structure
> - creates a source-matching destination symbolic link file structure pointing to each source-matching file

You only need to set the `$src` value to point to the source root folder location and the `$dest` value to point to the root destination folder  location—the other logic will do all the rest.

```
$src = "C:\Source\Folder\"
$dest = "C:\Destination\Folder\"
$src = $src.Replace("\","\\")

$i = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $src -Recurse
$i | % { Process {
    $apath = $_.FullName -Replace $src,""
    $cpath = $dest + $apath
    If(!(Test-Path (Split-Path -Parent $cpath))){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path (Split-Path -Parent $cpath)}
    If(!$_.PSIsContainer){If(!(Get-Item $cpath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){New-Item -Path $cpath -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value ([WildcardPattern]::Escape($_.FullName)) -Force}}
    }}
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)
- [Test-Path](https://ss64.com/ps/test-path.html)
- [Split-Path](https://ss64.com/ps/split-path.html)
- [Get-Item](https://ss64.com/ps/get-item.html)
- [Common Parameters](https://ss64.com/ps/common.html)

  - `ErrorAction`

    - > Control command behavior when an error occurs [enum]
      > Valid values: **Continue , Stop, Suspend, SilentlyContinue, Ignore, Inquire**. [Enum]
      > e.g. `-EA SilentlyContinue` will supress errors from being printed to stderr.
- [New-Item](https://ss64.com/ps/new-item.html)

Comment: @Churchill .... One thing I noticed testing from a non-admin account, in order to create symlinks, I had to elevate permission. Keep this in mind as you test just in case you have the same issue.

Comment: Run `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Scripts\AnyPScript.ps1"` just like that from a batch or cmd to execute the logic within the Powershell script. I assume you are already familiar with that too but just in case I wanted to mention.

Comment: Thanks! I've tested this with all my files and it works great. Thanks for all your time helping me.