# Copying Folders With a Certain Name to Another Folder While Preserving Folder Structure

Tags: windows-7, copy

There are a lot of instructions how to copy certain files from one folder to another folder and preserving the folder structure. I can do this with xcopy [srcFolder][Filename] [DestFolder] /S /K /Y.

However, what I need is searching for a certain folder name and then copy that folder along with all it's content to the destination folder. So let's say I have the following:

```
SrcFolder   
   -Folder 1
          -MySubfolder
             -File1_1.txt
             -File1_2.jpg
          -AnotherSubfolder
             -File1_3.txt
    
   -Folder 2
          -MySubfolder
             -File2_1.txt
             -File2_2.jpg
          -AnotherSubfolder
             -File2_3.txt
```

Now I would like to copy all "MySubfolder" folders incl their content. So at the end my target directory will look like this

```
DstFolder
   -Folder 1
      -MySubfolder
         -File1_1.txt
         -File1_2.jpg
   -Folder 2
      -MySubfolder
         -File2_1.txt
         -File2_2.jpg
```

How can I achieve this? Note that I am on Windows 7 so I don't have access to robocopy

Comment: Do you have access to PowerShell on your Windows 7 instance? Search for PowerShell solutions for this task with [`Get-ChildItem`](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html) using `-include "*MySubfolder*" -recurse` or something along those lines. Should be a simple trivial matter to get setup with PowerShell.

Comment: I have seen the get-childitem command but everything was about files. So I tried your "*MySubfolder*" option and that got me further. So I did Get-ChildItem -Path $src -include "*[DirectoryName]*" -recurse | foreach { copy-item -Path $_ $dst -recurse } However, that gives me the error copy-item:AnItem with the specified name ... already exists. The destination folder is empty, though so it really doesn't exist.

Comment: Try `foreach { copy-item -Path $_ $dst -recurse -force }` and don't forget about `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` too as it might help with that error. Otherwise you can wrap in an `If(!(Test-Path $_)){ copy-item -Path $_ $dst -recurse -force }` or something like that. Good job, keep digging at it, you are doing great! This answer might be somewhat helpful too for those things I mention: https://superuser.com/questions/1562774/copy-files-as-symlinks-and-maintain-the-directory-structure-on-windows/1564600#1564600.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use anything C to Java, VBS, PS or good ol' batch scripts. If you want to go down the nostalgia road, here we go:

```
CurrentDir
  + Love Letters
    my_love.txt
    breakup.txt
    new love.txt
  + Confidential
    + FBI
      + JFK Murder
        + eye witness report.txt
    + CIA
      + Area 51
        + UFO.jpg
```

### script.cmd

```
@ECHO OFF

@SETLOCAL
@SET SearchPath=%1
@SET SearchForDir=%2
@SET DestinationDir=%3

@FOR  /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S /A:D "%SearchPath%" ^|findstr /e "%SearchForDir%"') DO @SET DirPath=%%~a

@xcopy "%DirPath%" "%DestinationDir%/%SearchForDir%" /S /K /Y /I

echo DirPath %DirPath%

@ENDLOCAL

@ECHO ON
```

*(minor note, I made the search case sensitive so that **MySubFolder** would appear like that, otherwise, since Windows is case insensitive  you might get all the stuff you want in a directory called **mysUbFoldEr** if that was your search string)*

You can either call it via command line using parameters:

```
script.cmd <search_path> <dir_to_search_for> <destination_path>
```

For example

```
script.cmd . "FBI" "D:\Public"
```

Or you can just manually set the local envvars and run it manually with hardcoded values. Your choice.

If you want a shorter version, just replace the envvars with the parameter vars. I only did it so it'd be easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that script. However, it gives me the error "FINDSTR: Cannot open Folder. Invalid number of parameters. Please note that 'Folder' is part of the SearchForDir, i.e. "My Folder". I put the second argument between quotes and I see you also accounted for that in your script so I am not sure why it only takes the second part of "My Folder".

Comment: Well I did test it beforehand and with the dir structure I showed you as example (confidential and love letters) it worked fine. Spaces in paths are usually an issue with old batch scripts. Have you tried to hardcode values in the vars just for testing purposes?